# Return value instead of putting the result inside a variable. Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

This code below going to load json file asynchronously and insert the result inside the `_values` variable.

```
private getValue(name) {
this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getValue/' + name)
  .subscribe(res => this._values = res.json());
}
```

What I want is just to return one value, like normal JS function. I don't want the result to be stored inside variable. I just want the function to return a value.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can not return from an asynchronous method...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 private getValue(name) : any {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getValue/' + name)
                    .map(res => res.json());
 }
```

OR :

```
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

 private getValue(name) : Promise<any>{
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getValue/' + name)
                        .toPromise()
                        .then(response => response.json());
 }
```

then you would call this method with

```
Promise<any> myvar = getValue(name);
```